# Extjs: how Element's up/down functions work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I have some extjs code to support, but I have a problem with understanding those up/down functions in extjs Elements. Current question is `selector` parameter. Documentation says that it should be CSS selector, but I don't get how to set it up. E.g. I have some view like that:

```
Ext.define('ETaxi.settings.view.InfoPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.infopanel',
    title: i18n.settings.info.title,

    defaultType: 'displayfield',

    items: [{
        fieldLabel: i18n.settings.info.label,
        name: 'title'
    }]
});
```

How can I set up it's CSS selector in order to get this element from hierarchy via up/down functions?

Any additional information about those functions workflow is invited. Thank you.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, I'd suggest rephrasing it. `up` lets you find a parent node that matches some selector, `el.up('.foo')` finds an element above me in the hierarchy with the `className=foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  a panel has a button inside and you have a reference to that button you can do:

var myDesiredPanel=someButtonReference.up('infopanel'); //we are using the xtype to find it.
This time we use up because the button is inside the panel.

If on the other hand the panel is inside let say a viewport you could do:

var myDesiredPanel=referenceToMyVieport.down('infopanel');

**About the selector, it means that you can do:**

```
 myDesiredPanel = referenceToMyVieport.down('infopanel[title=MyInfoPanel]');
```

**you would fetch only an infopanel who's title is MyInfoPanel, you can use any config of the object to do this discrimination**

**Here is an example of the code where we fetch an specific button inside a panel through down https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1p6 you can modify it in this fiddle and look how it works.**

Comment: is there any way to define selector not using xtype? Because if I have several forms or buttons in component, down's behaviour becomes very weird.

Comment: Set a config in your button itemId='someId' then  var my specificButton = referenceToParentPanel.down ('button [itemId=someId]');  This is already in the answer, didn't work?

Comment: I've added a working example to the answer so you can look at the code and see it working.